# Folding basket - is there such a thing?

Tags: commuter, rack, cargo

I'd like to be able to go to a grocery (or some other) store on my commute from work. I've got a rear rack (b-tween).
I know, that I can permanently mount a basket on it, but I'd prefer not to since it makes noise, can be too wide and so on (and looks uncool for me, yes).

So, are there any folding baskets or some alternatives to use?

**edit**
The accepted answer is not about baskets, that's true, but it really about a thing I needed.

To clarify: I want something that I can fold and put inside my backpack (not a big one) and unfold when needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A subset of panniers that are designed for shopping bags are often called "grocery panniers," the distinguishing features being an open top and dimensions similar to the base of a paper grocery bag (not that you can get those very much anymore).

They are typically easily removable (just hooks), and in my experience do not bounce around alot, as was suggested in another answer. There is an elastic cord to the lower hooks that keeps them secure.

If you want to leave them on your bike, they do fold compactly against the rack and usually have velcro or snap closures to hold them folded. I usually just remove them when I'm not using them.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: This is as close to what I was looking for as it can be, thanks, will try to find some of those in my location

Comment: So just to be clear, as this is now the accepted answer the OP didn't want a basket or as the title suggests a "Folding Basket" but indeed wants essentially a Pannier or Rucksack.

Comment: Maybe @K102 can edit his question to reflect the accepted answer to avoid confusion later on when someone else asks for Folding Baskets and it gets flagged for duplicate when it clearly isn't

Comment: I've had something similar on my bike for about a decade and they work great.  [This](https://hollandbikeshop.com/en-gb/bicycle-bags/fastrider-panniers/fastrider-double-pannier/fastrider-double-pannier-cargo-led-silver/) is the updated version of what I have.  They'll easily hold 6 full bags of groceries (single-use USian plastic bags).  They work well for bikepacking as well.  The only downside is that you need a rack that extends a good distance rearwards near the axle; [this](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009VU3RAU/) is the one I use.

Comment: @DanK thx, added a bit of clarification. Thats true - I didnt know what I was asking about since I never heard of these grocery panniers

Comment: Are they waterproof?  Important property for grocery bags.

Answer (score 4):

The word "basket" brings to my mind something made of wire or  wicker. These can be clunky, heavy, noisy and ugly. as Dan K said, they do make folding baskets with the drawbacks he lists.

The word "pannier" brings to mind something that clips on to a rack mounted on the rear of the bike. They are usually made of cloth, some of them are easily removable, and some of them double as a backpack or satchel when removed. There are many designs, sizes and styles to choose from.
Here is one example (not an endorsement):
[image]

There are many reviews available to aid your research, google "bicycle panniers". Here's [one to get you started](https://www.cyclingabout.com/list-of-convertible-backpack-panniers-that-can-be-strapped-to-your-back-or-bike/)

Comment: The one you show looks like it's designed to carry a laptop and so on, with a lot of padding and small-ish compartments. Such a design isn't really suitable for shopping, unless you're buying things that are shaped like laptops and pads of paper. Something more like the Ortlieb Back Rollers (very much an endorsement), which are just a single large  compartment, would be much better for shopping (and I've used them very happily for that).

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are correct, the image I provided was not shopping specific. The original post said "go to a grocery (or some other) store on my commute from work" so I understood the question to include grocery but not be limited to grocery. My intent was to offer an alternative to baskets. This image was just one example of the many varieties of panniers available and to illustrate the method of mounting and removal.

Comment: Good point. Indeed, "office" pannier on one side, "shopping" pannier on the other might be a viable set-up!

Comment: I've actually got one of those exact panniers and it doesn't hold much. I've also killed the main zip in less than 3 years of daily commuting, probably by stuffing too much shopping in there

Comment: @ChrisH So, not only is it (not an endorsement) but based on your experience it's a recommended don't buy.

Comment: I have very simple panniers from Aldi with a single big compartment and a raincover that is zipped into the bottom. They were 2 for 10€ and they've lasted 3 years of daily commuting and weekly grocery shopping and are just now starting to get holes around the base and look worn out around the hooks. So I'd say get something simple and try whether you like panniers. You can always get something fancier if you find that you need it.

Comment: @DavidD I wouldn't go quite that far - within limits it's OK. It's the best backpack pannier I've come across, but I'm heavy on kit and often find myself with extra stuff to carry. Essentially my brute force and ignorance is too much for it to last as long as I want. Others would buy new panniers more often anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A short answer is yes, however they're mostly a wire folding design.

A quick Google search provided lots of results but only you know the style or design you need or want for your bike.

Will it look cool ? NO

Will it rattle with every bump ? YES

Do they exist? Most definitely

Comment: I was hoping there are some baskets with design like a tourist tent. But it seems that it's a good thing to try some diy

Comment: @k102 The problem with that is that there is no real benefit compared to just wire unless it's watertight. If it's watertight you basically have a pannier. A pannier also "folds" in the sense that it's smaller when empty and can be rolled up or something.

Comment: Yes - I have one and this describes it well.  Also the folding ones have a far lower carrying capacity than a cloth pannier - mine's rated at 8 kg  maximum.   And it hangs on the side of the parcel rack.  Mine also causes heel interference unless I mount it more aft of the rear axle, screwing up balance and weight distribution.   And it clatters something awful.  Plus side winds are worse.  On the plus side, makes the bike less stealable :)